# How to conver string to int in implode combinate with array_filter and array_map

Tags: php

How can i remove text from values ? i like values of array to be numbers only.

```
        $arr = Array(
            '39' => Array(
                    '0' => '307'
                    ),
            '42' => Array(
                    '0' => '329ds',
                    '1' => '300'
                    )
               );

$result = implode(",", array_filter(array_map(function($v){
  return implode(",", array_filter($v));
}, $arr)));

echo $result;

//result: 307,329ds,300
```

i tried to add (int) on implode() and its working but returning only 2 numbers instead of 3 numbers

```
            $arr = Array(
            '39' => Array(
                    '0' => '307'
                    ),
            '42' => Array(
                    '0' => '329ds',
                    '1' => '300'
                    )
               );

$result = implode(",", array_filter(array_map(function($v){
  return (int)implode(",", array_filter($v));
}, $arr)));

echo $result;

//result: 307,329
```

Comment: _"but returning only 2 numbers instead of 3 numbers"_ - that's because you are imploding your $v content there, which for your second sub-array results in `329ds,300`. And casting that to int, of course only leaves the `329` part, everything else gets discarded.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your answer but this do not help me how to get correct results

Comment: Why are you using `array_filter` here to begin with? You do not want to filter out any of the array items, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast to (int) every subarray element.

```
    $result = implode(",", array_filter(array_map(function($v){
        return implode(",", array_filter(array_map(function($sv){ return (int)$sv;},$v)));
    }, $arr)));
```